# Gemini Blueprint - PackageAdmin service reference is returning null with spring mvc in IBM Liberty

Tags: spring-mvc, osgi, websphere-liberty, blueprint-osgi, eclipse-virgo

I am trying to deploy the spring osgi application in IBM Websphere liberty server using gemini blueprint virgo DM. While deploying the application, I am facing the below error, says " ....PackageAdmin service is required  . Can anyone has an idea on this?

> java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   org.osgi.service.packageadmin.PackageAdmin service is required    at
>   org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.io.internal.resolver.PackageAdminResolver$1.run(PackageAdminResolver.java:179)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.io.internal.resolver.PackageAdminResolver$1.run(PackageAdminResolver.java:174)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.io.internal.resolver.PackageAdminResolver.getPackageAdmin(PackageAdminResolver.java:174)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.io.internal.resolver.PackageAdminResolver.getImportedBundles(PackageAdminResolver.java:67)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.io.OsgiBundleResourcePatternResolver.findClassPathMatchingResources(OsgiBundleResourcePatternResolver.java:217)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.io.OsgiBundleResourcePatternResolver.findResources(OsgiBundleResourcePatternResolver.java:154)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.io.OsgiBundleResourcePatternResolver.getResources(OsgiBundleResourcePatternResolver.java:186)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractOsgiBundleApplicationContext.getResources(AbstractOsgiBundleApplicationContext.java:439)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.virgo.web.dm.ServerOsgiBundleXmlWebApplicationContext.getResources(ServerOsgiBundleXmlWebApplicationContext.java:346)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:270)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:248)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.parse(ComponentScanBeanDefinitionParser.java:87)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.NamespaceHandlerSupport.parse(NamespaceHandlerSupport.java:74)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1411)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1401)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:172)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.doRegisterBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:142)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.registerBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:94)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.registerBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:508)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:392)
>     ... 25 more

Comment: I believe the title is wrong, Gemini Blueprint is the implementation of blueprints in Eclipse Virgo, but the problem is related to IBM Liberty. So "Gemini Blueprint" should be remove from the title and also the tag eclipse-virgo should be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from fixpack 8.5.5.9 of Liberty, PackageAdmin will not be available to the application region unless you create a custom Liberty feature that exports the package admin service using the **IBM-API-Service**  header.

1. Create a Liberty feature as explained in [this article](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/twlp_feat_develop.html)
2. Make sure that the feature exports PackageAdmin as in the example below
3. Declare your custom feature to server.xml using **usr:myfeature**

   ```
   Subsystem-ManifestVersion: 1.0
   IBM-Feature-Version: 2
   IBM-ShortName: myfeature
   Subsystem-SymbolicName: myfeature;visibility:=public 
   Subsystem-Version: 1.0.0
   Subsystem-Type: osgi.subsystem.feature
   Manifest-Version: 1.0
   IBM-API-Service: javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory,
    org.osgi.service.packageadmin.PackageAdmin,
    org.osgi.service.cm.ConfigurationAdmin
   ```

According to the description of a [defect fix](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=180&uid=swg1PI57974) in 8.5.5.9 fixpack, IBM made this change because Liberty was leaking its own services to the application, so now the OSGi services registered by Liberty are not visible to the application unless you create a feature like the one below to export  explicitly those that you need.

Comment: @Romanato, thank u for the help. I can able to resolve the issue by applying ur steps.